# Substitute values from one pandas data frame to another based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got two data frames with multiple columns.

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['x', '-', 'z'], 'B': [1, 6, 9], 'C': [2, 1, '-']})
> df_1

   A  B  C
0  x  1  2
1  -  6  1
2  z  9  -

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['w', 'y', 'y'], 'B': [5, 6, 9], 'C': [2, 1, 8]})
> df_2

   A  B  C
0  w  5  2
1  y  6  1
2  y  9  8
```

How can I substitute values from one data frame to values from another, based on condition (boolean mask)? 
Here, missing values noted as `'-'`, and I want to use values from `df_2` instead to get result:

```
> df
   A  B  C
0  x  1  2
1  y  6  1
2  z  9  8
```

Comment: Your expected procedure and result please??

Comment: Thank you, didn't notice that I haven't add it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC you can create `boolean mask` with converting values to `string` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) and then compare with `-`. Last fill values with `-` from another `DataFrame` by [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) or [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) with inverting `mask` by `~`:

```
mask = df_1.astype(str) == '-'
print (mask)
       A      B      C
0  False  False  False
1   True  False  False
2  False  False   True

print (df_1.mask(mask, df_2))
   A  B  C
0  x  1  2
1  y  6  1
2  z  9  8

print (df_1.where(~mask, df_2))
   A  B  C
0  x  1  2
1  y  6  1
2  z  9  8
```

EDIT by comment:

One possible solution is by [su79eu7k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37363596/substitute-values-from-one-pandas-data-frame-to-another-based-on-condition#comment62254872_37364590), thank you:

```
masks = [('A', r'[a-zA-Z]'), ('B', r'\d'), ('C', r'\d')]; 
print pd.concat([~(df_1[col].astype(str).str.contains(regex)) for col, regex in masks], axis=1)
```

Another solution create `mask` - first [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) possible `NaN` values, then [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) missed values from `dict` to `NaN` and last find [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html) values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['-x', '-', np.nan],'B': [1, 6, 'Unknown'],'C': [2, 1, 'Missing']})
print (df_1)

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['w', 'y', 'y'], 'B': [5, 6, 9], 'C': [2, 1, 8]})
print (df_2)

mask_li = ['-','Unknown','Missing']  
d = {x:np.nan for x in mask_li}  

mask = df_1.fillna(1).replace(d).isnull()
print (mask)
       A      B      C
0  False  False  False
1   True  False  False
2  False   True   True

print (df_1.mask(mask, df_2))    
     A  B  C
0   -x  1  2
1    y  6  1
2  NaN  9  8
```

You can use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), but other data cannot contain values from list `mask_li`:

```
mask_li = ['-','Unknown','Missing']    

mask= df_1.copy()
for col in df_1.columns:
    mask[col] = mask[col].astype(str).str.contains('|'.join(mask_li))

print (mask)
       A      B      C
0  False  False  False
1   True  False  False
2  False   True   True

print (df_1.mask(mask, df_2))    
   A  B  C
0  x  1  2
1  y  6  1
2  z  9  8
```

But there can be problem, if another data contains values from `mask_li` e.g. `-`:

E.g.:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['-x', '-', '-z'], 'B': [1, 6, 'Unknown'], 'C': [2, 1, 'Missing']})
print (df_1)

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['w', 'y', 'y'], 'B': [5, 6, 9], 'C': [2, 1, 8]})
print (df_2)

mask_li = ['-','Unknown','Missing']    

mask= df_1.copy()
for col in df_1.columns:
    mask[col] = mask[col].astype(str).str.contains('|'.join(mask_li))

print (mask)
      A      B      C
0  True  False  False
1  True  False  False
2  True   True   True

print (df_1.mask(mask, df_2))    
   A  B  C
0  w  1  2
1  y  6  1
2  y  9  8
```

One possible solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['-x', '-', '-z'], 'B': [1, 6, 'Unknown'], 'C': [2, 1, 'Missing']})
print (df_1)

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['w', 'y', 'y'], 'B': [5, 6, 9], 'C': [2, 1, 8]})
print (df_2)

mask_li = ['Unknown','Missing']    

mask= df_1.copy()
for col in df_1.columns:
    column = mask[col].astype(str)
    mask[col] = (column.str.contains('|'.join(mask_li))) | (column == '-')

print (mask)
       A      B      C
0  False  False  False
1   True  False  False
2  False   True   True

print (df_1.mask(mask, df_2))    
    A  B  C
0  -x  1  2
1   y  6  1
2  -z  9  8
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Can you also please suggest me what to do if I've got several types of missed values, like `'-'`, `'Missed'`, `'Unknown'` and so on..

Comment: One way is  `mask = (df_1.astype(str) == '-') | ( df_1.astype(str) == 'Missed') ` , but it's not appropriate if list of missed values is too long.

Comment: @KatrinaMalakhova Then you may need regex to make more robust masks like `masks = [('A', r'[a-zA-Z]'), ('B', r'\d'), ('C', r'\d')]; print pd.concat([~(df_1[col].astype(str).str.contains(regex)) for col, regex in masks], axis=1)` that filters non-alphabet in column `A` and non-digit in column `B` and `C`.